# Conway's Proof of Laurent Series Development

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, complex-integration, laurent-series

I was learning Laurent development (Conway's text, page 107), where Conway uses a two-page (a little tedious) proof to show the existence of Laurent Series, and uniqueness is left as exercise. Then I checked Ahlfors but he uses the same procedure. But I think the proof can be greatly simplified as follows:

First, for any $z\in\text {ann}(a;R_1,R_2)$, choose $r_1,r_2$ s.t. $R_1<r_1<|z-a|<r_2<R_2$, and define $\gamma_1=r_1 e^{-i\theta},\gamma_2=r_2 e^{i\theta},\theta\in[0,2\pi]$.  We have
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_1}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}\text d w+\int_{\gamma_2}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}\text d w$$
by Cauchy's Integral Formula.
Now, we can **expand the integrand using geometric series**, then interchange the sum and integral since the series is uniformly convergence on $\{\gamma_1\},\{\gamma_2\}$:
\begin{align}f(z)=&\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_1}\frac{f(w)}{z-a}\sum_{k\geq 0} (\frac{w-a}{z-a})^k\text d w+\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_2}\frac{f(w)}{w-a}\sum_{k\geq 0}(\frac{z-a}{w-a})^k\text d w\\=&\sum_{k\leq-1}[\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-\gamma_1}\frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{k+1}}\text d w] (z-a)^k+\sum_{k\geq 0}[\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_2}\frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{k+1}}\text d w] (z-a)^k
\end{align}
But the integral $a_k=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(w)}{(w-a)^{k+1}}\text d w$ is independence of the choice of $\gamma=re^{i\theta}$, hence we obtained the desired expansion.

To prove the uniqueness, suppose $f(z)=\sum_k a_k(z-a)^k$, then the convergence must be uniform and absolute, hence we can integrate each item of $f/(z-a)^{n+1}$ to identify $a_n$:
$$\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\mathrm dz=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{a_n}{z-a}\mathrm dz=a_n$$ Done.

This proof uses the same method as Conway's proof of power series expansion of analytic functions, and is really straightforward and intuitive. I don't know if it's correct. **And why both Conway and Ahlfors use a more abstract and tedious way to develop the Laurent Series?** Feel free to point out any errors or share your understanding on this.

Comment: You may like to take a look at Henri Cartan's complex analysis text (page 85-86); there he proves existence and uniqueness of Laurent expansions in an annulus using this approach (expanding a geometric series). So, you may also find some of the other parts of the book to your liking.